# Why did php 8 break my foreach loop which works fine in php 7.4 and before?

Tags: php, xml, php-8

I have the below php from my website which pulls data from an xml object to output a list of adoptable dogs. For some reason though, when updating my site from php 7.4 to 8.0, the foreach loop gives the following error "Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given on line 54"

In my troubleshooting, it seems that the line in question has always evaluated to null even when using php 7.4, the foreach loop only seems to care in php 8.

Can someone help me make this code run in php 8? I have tried many things to no avail, but I am a total php amateur so I am hoping someone else can easily spot a fix.

Here is the structure of the xml the code is pulling from:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object 
    ( 
        [XmlNode] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] = SimpleXMLElement Object 
                        ( 
                            [adoptableSearch] => SimpleXMLElement Object               
                                 (
                                      [ID] => 12354566
                                      [Name] => Paco
                                      [Species] => Dog
                                      [Sex] => Male
                                      [PrimaryBreed] => Chihuahua
                                      [SecondaryBreed] => N/A
                                      [SN] => Spayed
                                      [Age] => 49
                                      [Photo] => https//g.petango.com/photos/128937931827.jpg
                                      [Location] => Shelter 2
                                      [OnHold] => No
                                      [Special Needs] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                           (
                                           )

                                      [NoDogs] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                           (
                                           )

                                      [NoCats] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                           (
                                           )
```

The problematic line in the code is this:
`foreach ($xmlWSIN->XmlNode->$counter->adoptableSearch as $output)`

Since $xmlWSIN->XmlNode->$counter->adoptableSearch is null, the foreach() wont run in php 8, but will in 7.4 which is so strange.

Here is the full code for the page:

```
$urlWSBase      = get_field('api_base_url', 'option');
$urlWSComplete  = "";
$daysAgo1       = date('m/d/yy',strtotime("-1 days"));
$error          = "No";
$urlWSAuthKey   = get_field('api_key', 'option');
$urlWSComplete  = createAdoptableSearch($urlWSBase,$urlWSAuthKey, '1');

if (strlen($urlWSAuthKey) != 50) { 
    $error = "Yes";
    echo "<font color='red'>Not a Valid AuthKey, please double check and resubmit</font><br>";
    exit();
}
$selfURLIN      = '';

$page_single = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'single_pet.php',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
));

if ( $page_single ) {
    $page = current( $page_single );
    $selfURLIN = get_permalink($page->ID);
}

$outputWS = file_get_contents( $urlWSComplete, false, stream_context_create( $arrContextOptions ) );
//If outputWS is not a boolean FALSE value
if ($outputWS !== false) {
    $xmlWS = simplexml_load_string($outputWS);
    $xmlWSArray = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($outputWS)),1);
    if ($xmlWS === false) {
        echo "Failed loading XML: ";
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            echo "<br>", $error->message;
        }
    } 
}
else {
    echo "There seems to be an error!";
}

function outputAdoptableSearch($selfURLIN,$urlWSAuthKeyIN,$xmlWSIN) {
$xmlArrayCount = count($xmlWSIN);
$counter = 0;

while ($counter < $xmlArrayCount - 1) {
    foreach ($xmlWSIN->XmlNode->$counter->adoptableSearch as $output) {
        $xmlSecondaryBreed = $xmlSpecialNeeds = $xmlNoDogs = $xmlNoCats = $xmlNoKids = "Not Defined";
        $xmlAnimalID        = $output->ID;
        $xmlName            = $output->Name;
        $xmlPhoto           = $output->Photo;
        $xmlSpecies         = $output->Species;
        $xmlSex             = $output->Sex;
        $xmlPrimaryBreed    = $output->PrimaryBreed;
        $xmlAgeMonths       = $output->Age;
        $xmlAnimalType      = $output->AnimalType;
        $xmlAgeGroup        = $output->AgeGroup;
        
        $formated_age = petAgeCalc( $xmlAgeMonths );
        $xmlAnimalDetailsLink = $selfURLIN . '?animalID='. $xmlAnimalID;
        $species_lowercase = strtolower($xmlSpecies);
        $sex_lowercase = strtolower($xmlSex);
        $breed_lowercase = strtolower($xmlPrimaryBreed);

        if( strpos( $xmlPhoto, '_TN1.jpg' ) ) {
            $explode_url = explode('_TN1.jpg', $xmlPhoto);

            $pet_pic = $explode_url[0] . '.jpg';
        } else {
            $pet_pic = $xmlPhoto;
        };


echo  '<li>
        <a href="' . $xmlAnimalDetailsLink . '">
        <div style="background-image: url(' . $pet_pic . ')" class="pet-pic"></div>
        </a>
        <p>' . $xmlName . '</p>
        <p>' . $formated_age . '</p>
        <p>' . $xmlSex . '</p>
        <p>' . $xmlPrimaryBreed . '</p>
        <a class="button more-info" href="' . $xmlAnimalDetailsLink . '">More Details</a>
    </li>';   

$counter++; 
 }
}
```

I cannot understand why the below modification to while loop in the outputAdoptableSearch function won't fix the issue. The page simply wont load and will time out after 5 minutes with the below modification.

```
while ($counter < $xmlArrayCount - 1) {
    foreach ($xmlWSIN->XmlNode->$counter as $output) {
        $xmlSecondaryBreed = $xmlSpecialNeeds = $xmlNoDogs = $xmlNoCats = $xmlNoKids = "Not Defined";
        $xmlAnimalID        = $output->adoptableSearch->ID;
        $xmlName            = $output->adoptableSearch->Name;
        $xmlPhoto           = $output->adoptableSearch->Photo;
        $xmlSpecies         = $output->adoptableSearch->Species;
        $xmlSex             = $output->adoptableSearch->Sex;
        $xmlPrimaryBreed    = $output->adoptableSearch->PrimaryBreed;
        $xmlAgeMonths       = $output->adoptableSearch->Age;
        $xmlAnimalType      = $output->adoptableSearch->AnimalType;
        $xmlAgeGroup        = $output->adoptableSearch->AgeGroup;
        
        $formated_age = petAgeCalc( $xmlAgeMonths );
        $xmlAnimalDetailsLink = $selfURLIN . '?animalID='. $xmlAnimalID;
        $species_lowercase = strtolower($xmlSpecies);
        $sex_lowercase = strtolower($xmlSex);
        $breed_lowercase = strtolower($xmlPrimaryBreed);

        if( strpos( $xmlPhoto, '_TN1.jpg' ) ) {
            $explode_url = explode('_TN1.jpg', $xmlPhoto);

            $pet_pic = $explode_url[0] . '.jpg';
        } else {
            $pet_pic = $xmlPhoto;
        };
```

Comment: I can't actually see where in that code you call `outputAdoptableSearch`. Please try to reduce your code to a [mre] - some actual XML (print it out using `->asXML()`, not `print_r`), and a basic `while` loop and `foreach` loop, something like this: https://3v4l.org/o1OWT Then click [edit] and replace the code you have in the question with that, so that we can reproduce the problem, and help you understand why it happens.

Comment: As a first tip, though, have a look at the [SimpleXML examples in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). In particular note the first `<movie>` element is accessed as `$movies->movie[0]`, not `$movies->movie->0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap your `foreach` loops in a `if` statement to be sure that you don't feed the loop with wrong information.

Please try the code below:

```
if(is_array($my_variable)){
    foreach($my_variable as $whatever){
         // your code here
    }
}
```

With this you will be sure that your `foreach` will loop around an array.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much for everyone's input. I was able to implement a fix by changing the below line:

foreach ($xmlWSIN->XmlNode->$counter->adoptableSearch as $output)

to

foreach ($xmlWSIN->XmlNode[$counter][0] as $output)